# access MarkerClusterer from webpack under rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am developing an application that uses Google Maps with rails 6 .

I am stuck with  a problem that's probably resides on my lack of knowledge of webpack.

I am following the Google tutorials and I am able to show markers on a map. The next step is to use  clustering.

When I add the following script to “app/views/layouts/application.html.erb”, everything works.

As I well know, this is not the way I should do it. The right way to do it  is to use the markerclusterer Library  under  webpack, And to do so I did the following:

1.  included the Library  with npm (npm i @google/markerclustererplus).

2. Added to the end of “app/javascript/packs/application.js” the line

import * as MarkerClusterer from ‘@google/markerclustererplus’;

And since it didn't work, I tried

import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclustererplus';

and

import { MarkerClusterer } from '@google/markerclustererplus';

(Tried also with the outdated '@google/markerclusterer' Library,  with the same results)

3. Compiled it  with ./bin/webpack-dev-server and restarted the server (rails s)

4.  execute the application  on the browser. It does not cluster anything, Showing only the markers, and the web console shows the message “ReferenceError: MarkerClusterer is not defined” pointing to the following line:

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

Since it was working with the library included in a script, appears to me that the problem is not with the application itself,  but with some webpack configuration   I am missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Bellow is the application.js  file. My JavaScript application is under the “custom” directory

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("custom")


import * as MarkerClusterer from "@google/markerclustererplus";
```

=========================================================================

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/users/6826288/ravenous Plan,  but first let me present  the directory tree  of the directory app/javascript/:

> tree app/javascript/

app/javascript/

```
├── channels
│   ├── consumer.js
│   └── index.js
├── custom
│   ├── index.js
│   └── mapas
│       └── index.js
└── packs
    └── application.js
```

1)  I removed the line

import * as MarkerClusterer from "@google/markerclustererplus";

from app/javascript/packs/application.js and moved it to the top of   app/javascript/custom/mapas/index.js

2) compiled it with ./bin/webpack-dev-server and got tons of errors. Seems  the parameter  should be  a JavaScript  file.

3) changed it to

import { MarkerClusterer } from   '@google/markerclustererplus/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js';

3) compiled it with ./bin/webpack-dev-server. Pass.

4) started the server (rails s)

5) Tried the web page and  got the following error:

TypeError: _google_markerclustererplus_dist_markerclustererplus_min_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.MarkerClusterer is not a constructorindex.js:98

====================================

answering https://stackoverflow.com/users/5540603/vepanimas  request:

File  app/javascript/packs/application.js (comment  lines ommitted)

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("jquery")
require("@google/markerclustererplus")
require("channels")
require("custom")

import {initMapMarkers} from "../custom/mapas/index.js"

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    window.initMapMarkers=initMapMarkers
})
```

File  app/javascript/custom/mapas/index.js (the file is big, inserting  only  the critical lines)

```
import { MarkerClusterer } from '@google/markerclustererplus/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js';

…

function initMapMarkers(lat_in, lng_in, rot_in) {

…

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
var markers1 = locais1.map(function(local, i) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: local,
        map: map,
    })
 })    
var markerCluster1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers1);

...
```

Is basically the same code presented in Google's tutorial: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering?hl=pt-br

Comment: the missig script: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markerclustererplus/2.1.4/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>

Comment: You should import it where you actually need it (`custom` directory). Webpack will make sure to provide it to you.

Comment: Could you please share the file where you use an imported variable? I mean a file with this line `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);`?

Comment: I tried putting the import in custom file. Raised other error described in the text i added after my original question. Still lost...